# The following graph shows a distribution curve given by a function of the form $f(x)=A/(x+2e^{rx})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

The following graph shows a distribution curve given by a function of the form $$f(x)=\dfrac{A}{x+2e^{rx}}$$

[image: Graph to the question]

Determine the equation $f(x)$ of the graph.

Comment: Do you mean $xe^r$ or $e^{rx}$?

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please typeset your equations using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, kindly include how you have tried to approach the problem so that we know you are not just trying to get your homework solved and can offer you focused guidance.

Comment: Do you mean: $$f(x)=\frac{A}{x+2e^{rx}}$$

Comment: yeah @projectilemotion

Comment: One easy way to do it is to use two of the points you were given and solve the resulting system. In my opinion, the easiest way is to first use $(0,10)$, then $(1,12)$.

Comment: I am just confused with this only problem. What do you mean by solve the resulting system using the two points?

Comment: Note that you are given that $f(0)=10=\frac{A}{2}$ and $f(1)=12=\frac{A}{1+2e^{r}}$. Hence, you should solve the following system for $A$ and $r$:
$$\begin{cases} A/2=10 \\ \frac{A}{1+2e^r}=12 \end{cases}$$
Can you do this? If you have solved it correctly, evaluating $f(x)$ at $x=2$ with your values of $A$ and $r$ should return $f(2)=9$.

Comment: Yeah I can handle it from there thank you so much. I did get 9 when plugging in 2 as x. Thanks once again!

Comment: There are three given points and two constants, So one point should be deleted.  The $y$ coordinate of a third given point cannot be accurately and independently given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given form $f=\frac{A}{1+2e^{rx}}$ and by checking the points on the graph we get
$$\begin{aligned}
10&=f(0)=\frac{A}{0+2e^{r\cdot0}}=\frac{A}{2} \implies A=20 &&(\text{I})\\
12&=f(1)=\frac{A}{1+2e^{r\cdot1}}\overset{\text{(I)}}{=}\frac{20}{1+2e^r} &&\text{(II)}\\
9&=f(2)=\frac{A}{2+2e^{r\cdot2}}\overset{\text{(I)}}{=}\frac{10}{1+e^{2r}} &&\text{(III)}\\
\end{aligned}$$
transform (II):
$$
12=\frac{20}{1+2e^r} \iff 12(1+2e^{r})=20 \iff 24e^{r}=8 \iff e^r=\frac{1}{3} \iff r=\ln\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)
$$
So
$A=20$ and $r=\ln(\frac{1}{3})\approx -1.0986$. (III) is not needed for this.